# google fusion tables, draw a circle around the marker

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, overlay, ondraw

I used google fusion tables to draw on a map because I have no clue on how to do anything related to web development dunno how to write/use (HTML,javascript,PHP, etc..)..all I want to do is draw a 1 kilo circle around the marker with the same color as the marker.. I was easily able to do so on android using the onDraw method canvas and put it in the overlay class, and show the map on the emulator.. I wanna do the same on google fusion tables.. there is a link that says "configure info window" when I click on it an HTML code for the marker appears so is there like extra lines I could put in there to draw a circle with the maker? if not .. there must be somewhere I could type a similar piece of code like the "java onDraw method" right?.. help me please? :)